# jQuery Bootstrap notify prevent submitting form

Tags: jquery, notify

I have jQuery notify that posts warning messages based on certain selections: What I need to do is to not to submit the form when the warning/notification message shows up. Only when the error is resolved, is to submit the form. Form gets submitted when btnQuoteVariances is clicked. The issue is that notify is not a function so I can't really use return false or event.preventDefault() here.

```
$('.Reason').change(function(event)
{
    var id = $(this).data('item-id');
    var sPrice = $(this).data('price');
    var reason = $(this).val();
    var aPrice = $(this).data('aPrice');


    if (reason > 0 && (aPrice == sPrice)){

        $('##' + id).notify(
        {
            title: 'Warning',
            text: "Both pricing can't match, Please fix before conitniuing.",
            image: '<i class="fa fa-2x fa-exclamation-circle"></i>'
        },
        {
            style: 'cosentino',
            className: 'error',
            position: 'top center',
            clickToHide: true,
            autoHide: false
        });

    }

   $('##frmJobEntry').validate(
    {
        errorClass: 'JoblineInlineError'
    });

    $("##btnQuoteVariances").click(function(event)
    {

        $('.txtShopPrice').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.txtRevisedUnitPrice').prop('disabled', false);



    });
```

Comment: `$('##' + id)` is this a typo with double `#`?

Comment: no, this is within coldfusion code, so that's why ##

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```js
$("form").on("submit",function(e) {
  const $reason = $(".reason");
  const id = $reason.data('item-id');
  const sPrice = $reason.data('price');
  const reason = $reason.val();
  const aPrice = $reason.data('aPrice');
  if (reason > 0 && (aPrice == sPrice)){
    e.preventDefault();
  }  
})
```